# How to display query results depending of the IDs of the submitted form? (php)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, foreach

I'm trying to display results of a query with a paticuliar structure but I'm failing everytime.

To explain in details: Here is the concerned table in the database [image: table].

The `submission_id` refer to the ID of the submitted forms: First form submitted will have `submission_id = 1`, second one will have `submission_id = 2`, etc...

The `form_id` refer to the differents forms. The one I'm interrested for is the `form_id = 6`

The `fiel_id` refer to the ID of each field of the form. Ex: Field one, Name, has `field_id = 1`, etc...

There can be multiple `submission_id` for each logged user (depending of how many times he submit the concerned form). To test the code, I submitted 2 times the form. I made the next query to get all result interesting me (`$sub_id_string` is a variable contaning the `submission_id` of the forms submitted by the logged user. In this case `$sub_id_string = 5,6`) :

```
$result_id = array();
$result_sub_id = array();
$result_id_id = array();
$result_id_key = array();
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( 
    $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT value, field_id, submission_id
    FROM  wp_fusion_form_entries
    WHERE field_id IN (6,7,8,19,20,21,22,23,24,28,29,32) AND form_id = '6' AND submission_id IN ($sub_id_string)
    ORDER BY submission_id, field_id
    ")
);
foreach($result as $key => $results){
    $result_id[] = $results->value;     // All values (50kg, no, 170...60kg, yes, 165...)
    $result_sub_id[] = $results->submission_id;     // submission IDs (5,5,5...6,6,6...)
    $result_id_id[] = $results->field_id;       // IDs of field_id (6,7,8,19....6,7,8,19...)
    $result_id_key[] = $key;            // keys of results
}
```

I printed the different arrays to check, everything is ok. Now things getting harder. What I want to do:

Display results like this:

```
//For the first submission (ex: submission_id = 5)
<h1> My informations </h1>
Name: value 1
Forname: value 2
....
Weight: value 12

//If there is a 2nd submission (ex: submission_id = 6)
<h1> My informations </h1>
Name: value 1
Forname: value 2
....
Weight: value 12

// etc... if there are more submissions
```

This drives me crazy! I'm sure the answer is under my eyes but I didn't succeed yet.. If you have any advice I'll be honored to read them! Thanks by advance :)

Comment: what actually is your problem ? (i.e. what is the result of your script ? display nothing ?)

Comment: If the user submit multiple times the form, i would a way to do something like: For each submission_id, display associated values. In this case: For submission_id = 5,display all values that match submission_id = 5. Then for submission_id = 6, display all values that match submission_id = 6, etc . I tried a lot of ways to do this but everytime it failled, so I didn't post it

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the results by the submission id.

```
<?php

$result = $wpdb->get_results (
    $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT value, field_id, submission_id
    FROM  wp_fusion_form_entries
    WHERE field_id IN (6,7,8,19,20,21,22,23,24,28,29,32) AND form_id = '6' AND submission_id IN ($sub_id_string)
    ORDER BY submission_id, field_id
    ")
);

$grouped = array();

foreach($result as $key => $results){
    if (!isset($grouped[$results->submission_id])) {
        $grouped[$results->submission_id] = array(
            'fields' => array() // to store all fields for this submission
        );
    }

    $grouped[$results->submission_id]['fields'][$results->field_id] = array(
        'field_id' => $results->field_id,
        'field_value' => $results->value,
    );
}

// now you have an array of submissions with the field values
// you can iterate with foreach
foreach ($grouped as $submissionId => $submission) {
    foreach ($submission['fields'] as $field) {
        echo "field: " . $field['field_id'] . "<br />";
        echo "value: " . $field['field_value'] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man thanks a lot! This is what I expected! You are the best!  :D I upvoted but it's not displayed for people with less than 15 reputation points :(